# Is there a transition coordinator (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) for show/hide keyboard animation in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am looking to run some animation alongside the keyboard show/hide animation. I know that I can use a UIView animation block to achieve the same behavior, but, im also trying to get some information about how the parent view controller is going to animate during the show/hide animation. I am presenting a UIViewController as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet and when one of the text fields in my parent controller becomes the first responder, the parent controller moves up to the top of the screen (on iPad) on its own. Which is a nice handy feature of iOS, but, I cannot for the life of me figure out HOW much the parent controller is going to move, which is needed for me to accurately determine how far I need to move the subview (text field) that will be covered by the keyboard.

I was hoping that the transition coordinator (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) would help me figure this out during that animation, but, to my dismay there doesnt seem to be a transition coordinator during the keyboard animation. Is there a way to get one? or where I can find one? any idea how to know how much my parent, form sheet, view controller is going to move when the keyboard is shown/hidden?

Ive done some scowering on the webs to see if there are any answers and the only ones I really find suggest using a UIPresentationController. While im not entirely opposed to this, it would require quite a bit of retooling of my current controller heiarchy as well as the fact that it doesnt really seem to give me the information i still need to solve this problem. Anyway, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!